# Algorithm for meshing parametric manifolds with dimension higher than 3?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm for meshing parametric manifolds in a given range. To be specific, in n-dimensional space, the manifolds are given as $$x=e^{At}x_0$$ where $x_0$ are the solutions of a linear equation $$Fx=g$$

$x_0$ is an (n-2)-dimensional linear set. For example, in 4-dimenional space, $x_0$ is a 2d plane, and the manifold is 3d.

I did some searching, and the algorithms I can are usually used to mesh manifolds given as explicit funstions.

Any clue such as an algorithm name would be helpful, thank you.